# How to display the column "Version number" in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I have some files from a CAD software and these files have a "Version number" attribute along with the attributes "Source" and "Authors". I am able to enable the columns "Source" and "Authors" in Windows Explorer, but can't find a way to enable the column "Version number".

[image]

[image]

Anybody has an idea how to enable this column in Windows Explorer? None of the already existing answers on SuperUser seem to solve this problem. I would prefer to do this without the need to install 3rd party software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are not looking for "File version":

[image]

I have examined the list of columns, I assume the same as you did,
and have not found any other column which lists this property.

As in Windows 10 one cannot add any columns that are not in the list,
not even by using an Explorer extension, this is simply an omission
by Microsoft which users cannot correct.

If this is important for you, you would need to use another file manager
than Windows Explorer. The article
[Best Free File Manager](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-file-manager.htm)
has quite a list where you will surely find one that fulfills this condition,
although I can't point to one such.

Comment: Nope. You can see `File version` property inside _Description_ group, see e.g. property sheet of executables (`.exe`) and libraries (`.dll`) in `C:\Windows\System32` folder. The OP talks about the **entirely different** `Version number` property inside the _Origin_ group (seen e.g. on Microsoft Office documents).

Comment: @Biswapriyo: Yah, much too short. It takes much longer to give a negative answer.

Comment: No, File version is not displaying the value of that field.

Comment: @JosefZ Yes you are correct, this is the field that I am talking about.

Comment: Yes it seems that it is not possible to display this value without installing some shell extension or using a different file manager. Thanks all!